# Are there official statblocks for Vecna's constructs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, constructs

In the "Core Beliefs" section on Vecna, in Dragon Magazine 348, a holiday of the Clerics of Vecna is described. During this holiday, cultists try to create two powerful constructs. One of these is made of hands, and the other made of eyes. This ritual can only be performed with the right materials, on the correct date, and with the direct interference of Vecna himself. As such, succesful completion of the ritual is seen as a sign of great success and the favour of Vecna.
Both constructs are Large, and have an ability to drain the life of their opponents, by grappling or looking at them respectively.

Though the article was very detailed in describing how the constructs look and generally what they are capable of, I could not find an official statblock. Do these creatures have official stats anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes, but only in AD&D products

Stats for the Eye and the Hand do not appear in any official D&D 3rd edition books, based on the WotC [Monster Index](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/monsters) and [DragonDex Index of Monsters](https://www.aeolia.net/dragondex/monsters.html), and third-party publishers were forbidden from using the copyrighted Vecna name and lore.

However, they did appear in earlier AD&D sourcebooks, and conversion should to 3e not be too difficult, since they're both just advanced flesh golems with some unique abilities.

Statistics for **The Hand** appear in *Die Vecna Die* (2000), p.62,63,157. It is an intelligent flesh golem made entirely out of hands. It has telepathy, deals level drain and mummy rot on a melee hit, resists nonmagical weapons, and has 10HD instead of the usual 9HD.

**The Eye** appears  on page 115-116 of the same sourcebook. It is another unique intelligent flesh golem made entirely out of moist eyeballs. It has 12HD and does not strike in melee, but has 11 gaze attacks of which it can use five each round: *cause serious wounds*, *confusion*, *death spell*, *dispel magic*, *disintegrate*, *enervation*, *finger of death*, *flesh to stone*, *hold person*, *lightning bolt*, and *sleep*. It also has troll-like regeneration and resists nonmagical weapons. *Dispel magic* will destroy it temporarily, but it re-animates soon later.